# Possible to close executing bat file(s) pressing a button on keyboard?

Tags: batch-file

I had made an auto-backup for some videogame files and directorys. This little .bat just make a backup every 30 minutes. Now my problem is this: I want to close this window/process/file. Can I close it directly from itself if I press the X button on keyboard?
I've made this file on Win XP Home so please don't write commands that are only for WIN 10 or something else, if possible.
If it can be helpuful here is my .bat file code:

```
@echo off
:Minimize
if "%1" == "" start "" /min "%~f0" MY_FLAG && exit
:path ompressor
set d=%:\backup%
set e=%:\Documents and Settings\admin\Application Data\.minecraft%
:backup
set b=%date:/=%
set c=%time%
mkdir "C%d%\saves\%b%\%c%"
xcopy /s /e /y "C%e%\saves" "C%d%\saves\%b%\%c%"
set b=%date:/=%
set c=%time%
mkdir "C%d%\resorcepack\%b%\%c%"
xcopy /s /e /y "C%e%\resourcepacks" "C%d%\resorcepack\%b%\%c%"
msg * Worlds backupped!
:Countdown_Setup
set Days=0
set Hours=0
set Minutes=30
set Seconds=0
:Countdown
CLS
ECHO   %Days%  -  %Hours%  -  %Minutes%  -  %Seconds%
ECHO Days  Hours  Mins  Secs
sleep 1
IF "%Seconds%"=="0" (
    IF "%Minutes%"=="0" (
        IF "%Hours%"=="0" (
            IF "%Days%"=="0" (
                GOTO backup
            )
            SET /a Days -=1
            SET Hours=24
        )
        SET /a Hours -=1
        SET Minutes=60
    )
    SET /a Minutes -=1
    SET Seconds=60
)
SET /a Seconds -=1
GOTO Countdown
```

Sorry if I ask a so unusual thing but I searched a lot on the net and I've tried a lot of commands like IF, SET, AT, TSKILL.
I'm a bit new on programming so please make something steb-by-step if you can.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just hit `Alt` + `F4` or `Control` + `C`?

Comment: Instead of running the script constantly, why not just use the Scheduled Task Manager?

Comment: @FatalBulletHit Good idea, but I'd like to make something shorter. I think that something with `set /p exit=` and `if "%exit%"=="x" exit` cuold also close the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like your script ia heavy on memory, but regardless.

In your main script, after `@echo off` add:

```
Title gamebackup
```

Create a new batch file called. Killgame.cmd

The simply add:

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq  gamebackup*"
```

Then run the secondbatch to kill the process.

Comment: Thanks for the idea I've used `tskill cmd` because I've Win xp Home. Is it possible to make this in only one file?